# nunit.xamarin for iOS Unit test: Run tests button not visible

Tags: nunit

I am having an iOS unit test project, which was using Xamarin.Nunitlite. 
I migrated this to use nunit.xamarin. But I am not seeing "Run tests" button on UI. I am using nunit.xamarin nuget packages for visual studio 2015.

Can anyone help in this.? I was getting this button few days back while testing. Now I freshly created a project and the button is not visible.

Comment: Which version of the runner are you using - the 3.01 package released on nuget.org?

Comment: Yes, I verified again. Seems like it is layout issue . The button appears properly on ipad 9.x.  But has issues with ipad 10.x . Need to find the solution.

Comment: Ah ok. In that case, pull request would be very welcome, if you're willing! =D https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin

Comment: ya I just encountered the same thing... iPhone7 Simulator iOS 10.3 (14E269) (nunit 3.6.1 and assocated runner)